# Missing values vanish from expressions with DateObject and slot-lookup?

Tags: associations, date-and-time, slot

Missing value vanishes when adding or subtracting `DateObject` but only when slot-lookup is used, in an `Association` query:

Given

```
as = <|"a" -> <|"date" -> Missing[]|>, 
  "b" -> <|"date" -> DateObject[{2018, 2, 16}]|>|>
```

Then the query that subtracts a constant `DateObject` from both rows gives:

```
as // Query[All, (#["date"] - DateObject[{2013, 7, 1}]) &] // Query[All, FullForm]
```

(where the second query using `FullForm` is only for formatting purposes)

> <|a->Times[-1,DateObject[List[2013,7,1],"Day","Gregorian",-8.`]],b->Quantity[1691,"Days"]|>

pff, the missing value in row "a" disappears, which is not consistent with this alternative query:

```
as // Query[
  All, {"date", DateObject[{2013, 7, 1}] &} /* Apply[Subtract]]
```

> <|a->Plus[Times[-1,DateObject[List[2013,7,1],"Day","Gregorian",-8.`]],Missing[]],b->Quantity[1691,"Days"]|>

Same issue when substituting `Plus` for `Subtract`. Is this bug in DateObject or the slot lookup?

Comment: I guess you could reduce the question to "please explain this: `{Missing[]} // Query[# &]` and `{Missing[]} // Query[-# &]` and `{Missing[]} // Query[1 - # &]`"

Comment: In comparison to `-Missing[]`, `1 - Missing[]`, `1 - Missing[Indeterminate]`

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the reduction, ... or even `Missing[] // Query[-# &]` (without the `{...}`) So the problem is an interaction, but it's not just `Query` since `Missing[]//Query[f[#]&]` works. So does: `Missing[] // Query[Subtract[1, #] &]`